# Create empty file using two textboxes

Tags: vb.net, file

I'm creating a simple program that will allow the user to with the click of buttons to create empty files, delete files, rename them and much more. Now to my question. When I click on the `Create New File` button (obviously empty), I have a new window pop up.

In that window I want two textboxes and one button to be present. The first textbox shows the initial path to the file I want to create (i.e `C:\Users\Username\Desktop\`) and the second textbox will show the name plus extension of the file (i.e `Hero.dll`).

The button will then combine these and make the file and put it in the directory the textbox is displaying. However, I'm having trouble with the textbox displaying the name.

Also, the textbox displaying the path is called `txtPath` and the textbox displaying the name is called `txtName`.

So this

```
IO.File.Create(txtPath.Text, txtName.Text)
```

gives me this error

> Conversion from string "Hero.dll" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

and I noticed in the code (Intellisense I'm assuming is what it's showing in) it says

```
Functions File.Create(path As String, bufferSize as String) As Filestream
```

and so `bufferSize` is the `txtName` textbox by then.
How would one go about fixing this so `txtName` does what it's supposed to do, or do I simply have to roll with only displaying the path?

I have tried a couple of things myself but none worked the way I wanted it to.
Also, creation of the file works like a charm if the code only says

```
IO.File.Create(txtPath.Text)
```

given the name of the file is also displayed in the path.

I'm open for any kind of help, as I've tried several different "solutions" I've come up with myself. Thank you!

Comment: Use the `OpenFileDialog` class, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: _IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(txtPath.Text, txtName.Text))_

Comment: @Steve Sir, thank you very much. I didn't know Path.Combine existed. :) (I don't know how to upvote comments. I don't think I can, but I hope this comment is okay enough)

Comment: @Steve : Darn, you beat me to it. Takes too long to write answers from a phone. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter should specify ***both*** the path ***and*** the file name. You can, and should always, use [**`Path.Combine()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to concatenate paths and file names.

Also, the [**`File.Create()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) opens a [**`FileStream`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) to the file, which keeps it locked until you close it or the application. If you do not intend to use this `FileStream` to write data to the file you ought to dispose it so the file lock is released.

```
IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(txtPath.Text, txtName.Text)).Dispose()
```

Comment: Haha, you're good! Thank you anyway, by the time I asked I didn't know Path.Combine() worked. :D

Comment: Aight my bad. Accepted!

Comment: @Jezper : No problem. Good luck! :)